# DataGridView content is not printing

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

i have a `DataGridView` and by clicking print button it shows print preview and then by clicking on print button it supposed to print the print preview content.

The problem is my `DataGridView` content is displayed in print preview but when i save it as xps document. it doesn't show `DataGridView` content. although header and footer is there.but only `DataGridView` data is not printing.

Here is code to print `DataGridView` rows:

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, height, 
   dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), 
    dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(90, height, 
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, height, 
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), 
   dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black,  new System.Drawing.Rectangle(270, height, 
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, height, 
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString(), 

 dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(450, height, 
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, height, 
      dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString(),
  dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(670, height, 
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));
```

Comment: Besides being terribly convoluted (why not pull out the height and width into two varaibles?) the code, __if it indeed shows the content__ in the preview __seems__ ok. So how exactly are you coding the loop and setting up the document? Where do you calculate `height`? - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place debugger and check Data Source after click on print button might be it become reinitialize that why it's not binding your data

Comment: what if i use third party tool to print document like crystal report or itextsharp? is it OK to use a third party tool for ur project. i mean they didn't expire after sometime or not?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show your grid in just text format or pdf there is no need to use third party tool just use C# libraries to accomplish your task otherwise there is no issue to use third party tool which are free available

Comment: Please add this to your original answer. This is not a discussion forum, so don't create separate answers unless they are providing two fully separate answers.